# pytest add option to skip fixture setup

Tags: python, pytest

Suppose I have a subset of tests that utilize a pyserial connection. Skipping the associated test functions is mostly identical to the [`--runslow`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#control-skipping-of-tests-according-to-command-line-option) example from the docs.

My question is: how can I skip a fixture so that I don't get a test setup failed error? That is, if the device is not connected, an error is raised during fixture setup.

**EDIT** (bonus) maybe init the skip mark if automatically if connection fails altogether?

**EDIT 2** I guess I'm really asking which of the two `TODO`s is the "right" approach?

**EDIT 3** Maybe just set `autouse=False` and make sure each test function that uses the fixture is marked?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```py
# conftest.py

import pytest

from typing import List
from serial import Serial

from _pytest.nodes import Item
from _pytest.config import Config
from _pytest.config.argparsing import Parser


def pytest_addoption(parser: Parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--live",
        action="store_true",
        default=False,
        help="utilize serial connection"
    )


def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config: Config, items: List[Item]):
    if config.getoption("--live"):
        return
    skip = pytest.mark.skip(
        reason="needs '--live' option to run"
    )
    for item in items:
        if "live" in item.keywords:
            item.add_marker(skip)


# fixtures (port, etc.) for connection...


# TODO need to apply skip mark
@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def serial_connect(port: str, ) -> Serial:

    # TODO or catch and pass if config value is False
    with Serial(port=port, ) as new:
        yield new
```

Answer (score 1):

Had success with this implementation; would appreciate feedback:

```py
# conftest.py

import sys
import pytest

from typing import Optional
from serial import Serial, SerialException, \
    EIGHTBITS, PARITY_NONE, STOPBITS_ONE

from _pytest.config import UsageError
from _pytest.config.argparsing import Parser


def pytest_addoption(parser: Parser):

    parser.addoption(
        "--live", action="store_true", default=False,
        help="utilize serial connection for associated tests"
    )

    parser.addoption(
        "--port", action="store", type="string", default=None,
        help="serial port for establishing connection"
    )

    parser.addoption(
        "--timeout", action="store", type="float", default=None,
        help="port timeout for serial connection"
    )


@pytest.fixture
def live(request) -> bool:
    return request.config.getoption('live')


@pytest.fixture
def port(request) -> str:

    value = request.config.getoption('port')

    if value is not None:
        return value

    elif sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
        return "/dev/tty.SLAB_USBtoUART"

    elif sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
        return "/dev/ttyACM0"

    elif sys.platform.startswith('win32'):
        return "COM14"

    else:
        pytest.skip("unspecified '--port' option")


@pytest.fixture
def timeout(request) -> Optional[float]:
    return request.config.getoption('timeout')


@pytest.fixture
def connection(live: bool, port: str, timeout: Optional[float]) -> Serial:

    if not live:
        pytest.skip("needs '--live' option to run")

    try:
        with Serial(
            port=port,  baudrate=460800, bytesize=EIGHTBITS,
            parity=PARITY_NONE, stopbits=STOPBITS_ONE, timeout=timeout
        ) as s:
            yield s

    except SerialException as e:
        raise UsageError(
            "invoked '--live' option, but connection failed"
        ) from e
```

Comment: I've used this pattern for Great Good with things like skipping elasticsearch-dependent tests if no elasticsearch executable could be found. Though, I might suggest using `is_live` instead of the bare `live` for the fixture's name — for though it's annotated as bool, that annotation is not visible when the var is used; `is_live` discards any ambiguity "live" might be a verb (and thus prolly a method).

Comment: I don't think this answer can be improved any further, great job!